# How do I make input parameters with ArcGIS/Python?

Tags: python, gis, arcgis, arcpy

I am brand new to Python. I am trying to have the "source folder" and "geodatabase" be input parameters in an ArcGIS toolbox using the `arcpy.GetParameterAsText` function.

I'm really unsure of where to put the two `arcpy.GetParameterAsText` functions. Do I want to set the workspace to it? If I do that I don't know how to create the GDB file without the path before it.

```
# Set the workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\x\\Desktop\\Python_Scripting\\4\\Lesson4_Data\\Lesson4_Data"

#Create the GDB
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management("C:\\Users\\x\\Desktop\\Python_Scripting\\4\\Lesson4_Data\\Lesson4_Data","lesson4a.gdb")

# Set the feature class variables
fclist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("","polygon")
fctotal = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

# Start the loop on all feature classes
for fc in fclist:
    fcdesc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
    print fcdesc.basename + " is currently importing into the lesson4a.gdb."
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management (fc, "C:\\Users\\x\\Desktop\\Python_Scripting\\4\\Lesson4_Data\\Lesson4_Data\\lesson4a.gdb\\" + fcdesc.basename)
    print fcdesc.basename + " is done importing into the lesson4a.gdb.\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `arcpy.GetParameterAsText(#)` function will read an input parameter from an ArcGIS tool.

During scripting and debugging, it is simplest to hard-code the function's input variables to verify that the function is working. Once the tool is (essentially) the way you want it, create the toolbox and script tool within ArcMap.

To accept input parameters from the tool execution dialog, you'll need to **create them when creating the script tool** (and change the code to accept `GetParameterAsText` inputs). The best walkthrough for this is really the ArcGIS resource center.

- [Adding a script tool](http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#/Adding_a_script_tool/00150000001r000000/)
- [Setting script tool parameters](http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#//00150000000n000000.htm)

Within the Python script, I typically **read the input parameters first thing** -- that way, they are available as variables for all the rest of the script. The index value indicates which parameter is which.

```
# Input parameters
sourceFolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)        # first input parameter of script tool
geodatabaseName = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)     # second input parameter

# Set the workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = sourceFolder

#Create the GDB
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(sourceFolder, geodatabaseName)
```